# non-idiomatic synonym for "sanity check"

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a non-idiomatic word or phrase for ["sanity check"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check)?

(meaning a quick test of some system to see whether it is functioning properly)

Comment: "sanity test", "sanity check", and "smoke test" aren't idioms *per se*, they're technology metaphors turned jargon.  Technology uses metaphors constantly, like "garbage collection," "split," "slice," "kill," etc. etc.

Comment: 'test' alone implies trying something out ... and it would take some "testing" to "validate" something and perhaps "extensive testing" to "certify" something ?  "quick test" would emphasize that it wasn't a "careful test"

Comment: You could coin something, but it probably wouldn't be very pithy if you wanted it to be reasonably obvious in meaning. Maybe something like "quick feasibility check" (as opposed to a full *feasibility study*) or "plausibility check". Check out synonyms of *feasibility* for more options. I do think you'd want to stick with "check" rather than "test" or other similar terms if you want to imply a very brief, cursory examination. (You could also use "once-over" as in "viability once-over" but that sounds more idiomatic than "check" to me in this context.)

Comment: [limited technical inspection (LTI)](http://engineermaintenance.weebly.com/limited-technical-inspection-lti.html)

Answer (score 2):

*Reasonableness check* isn't a direct synonym but it's about as close as you're going to get.

There is a move in some circles to avoid *sanity check* along with other terms that could be interpreted as suggesting that mental health issues are inherently bad. *Sanity check* isn't widely used in the "quick test" sense in the question; in the technical fields I'm familiar with (hardware and software)  it's more about *thinking* through an idea looking for flaws that would make further work a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the word **validation**.  In engineering modeling, validation is a way of confirming that your model works well (i.e. it actually predicts reality).

Are sanity-checks necessarily quick?  I never felt that phrase connoted quickness.  Certainly, you could do a *quick* sanity check.  But, you could also perform one that took a long time.